# Read TempData value with javascript as a string

Tags: javascript

I passed  a data value into TempData in my controller

```
 TempData["Type"] = "success";
```

But When i read it with javascript , it shows me :

```
var title = @TempData["Type"]; // this return me : title=success not "success"
```

How i can read my data as `"success"` string ?

Comment: did you tryied to do a `typeof @tempdata["Type"]`?

Comment: what do you mean by `// this return me : title=success not "success"` - that's an assignment which usually doesn't return anything. WHAT is returning "title=success" ?

Comment: the variable title contains  **success**  not **"success"**

Comment: the debugger from Chrome/firefox/etc is very bad (and lot of times works wrong), is better if you put a console log or an alert to check the real information.

Comment: thnx for the advice @TiGreX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is this happening I dont know, but a way to solve this is force to be a string doing `.toString()`

see the example:

```
var k = 111111;
alert(typeof k);

var w = k.toString();
alert(typeof w);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9780sb12/

if you do

```
var title = @TempData["Type"].toString();
```

should force to be an string.